# Split a dataframe into smaller dataframes based on a column python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset :

[image: raw data]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: weekly output]

I know that i need to do this:

```
df= df.groupby('city_id').resample('W').agg({'Quantity':'sum'}, loffset = pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-8))
```

to get a weekly aggregation, but I need it grouped by city id THEN aggregated by week.

My thought is that I would need to create multiple dataframes, each one per city id, aggregate them by date to make the weekly output then concat them back together but I feel that there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df.groupby(['index', 'city_id'], as_index=False).sum()
```

This will group the first 2 columns and sum up the remaining ones.

Comment: this did not work :( it just removed my date index and replaced it with a new index

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

`output = df.groupby('city_id').resample('W').agg({'Quantity':'sum'}, loffset = pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-8))`